# Send xml data to the WCF REST service

Tags: wcf, rest

There is a self hosted WCF REST service, need to send an xml post message to it.
Seems like this question was asked and answered several times, but after trying every solution I still didn`t get any success.

Server: interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISDMobileService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    int ProcessMessage(string inputXml);
}
```

Server: class

```
public class Service : ISDMobileService
{
    public int ProcessMessage(string inputXml)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "ProcessMessage : " + inputXml );
        return 0;
     }  
}
```

Server: hosting

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebServiceHost          host    =   new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://172.16.3.4:7310"));
        WebHttpBinding          webbind = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None);

        ServiceEndpoint         ep      = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISDMobileService), webbind, "");
        ServiceDebugBehavior    stp     =   host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        stp.HttpsHelpPageEnabled    =   false;

        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Service is up and running. Press 'Enter' to quit >>>");
        Console.ReadLine();

        host.Close();
    }
}
```

[image: fiddler request]

Request from fiddler without anything in the "Request Body" works just fine and fires break point inside ProcessMessage method of Service class, any variant of data in "Request Body", 
e.g.: test || <inputXml>test</inputXml> || inputXml="test" ||  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><inputXml>test</inputXml> etc. gives HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Will appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- Since you're using `WebServiceHost`, you don't need to explicitly add the service endpoint (call to `host.AddServiceEndpoint(...)` in your Main.
- The operation takes a `string` parameter; if you want to send it in XML, you need to wrap the string in the appropriate element. Try this body and it should work:

Body:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">This is a string encoded in XML</string>
```

You can also send it in different formats, such as JSON. This request should work as well

```
POST http://.../ProcessMessage
Host: ...
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: <the actual length>

"This is a string encoded in JSON"
```